# Can't get gigabit connection on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking

I cannot get my PC to get gigabit speed. I searched everything on the web for help, but I have still 100mbps connection.

- I have CAT.5E cables both from modem-to-router and router-to-pc
- I have aTP-LINK ac750 router which support gigabit connection
- My motherboard GA-P41T-ES3G also support gigabit speed
- I updated the Realtek PCI egb driver and the firmware to the router
- In the device manager I set the speed and duplex connection to 1.0 gigabit full duplex

On some forum someone mentioned that I should disable IPv6 but it was never enabled in the first place.

Comment: What speed does your ISP say your connection is?

Comment: I subscribed for 500 / 200 mbps

Comment: What does a speed test show? http://www.speedtest.net and pick your closest test server.

Comment: http://www.speedtest.net/result/4641162706.png
But I will speak with the ISP tomorrow, maybe the problem is on their side

Comment: It would appear so ...